# SMS Inbox Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, sms, message, inbox

I would create an sms and save it into sms inbox.

I've tried using this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", phoneNumber);
values.put("date", time);
values.put("body", message);
values.put("type", 1);
values.put("read", 1);
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

This work on android 4.0.x, 4.1.x and 4.2.x, but don't work on android 4.4.

How can i set my message into the default message application?

Thank you to all.

Comment: Certainly we can, just like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697282/android-kitkat-api-19-how-to-write-messages-in-sms-content-provider-without

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i set my message into the default message application?

You cannot modify the SMS inbox [unless your app *is* the user's chosen SMS client](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) on Android 4.4+.

Comment: So, there is no solution?

Comment: @user3253955: Write a full SMS client app. Or, find an SMS client app that offers some sort of plugin interface, and write your code to support it.