# Android - Try to send fake sms to myself without mobile network usage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send message to my phone with this app, without using network usage, but my code doesn't work. I followed some tutorial, check android dev and I haven't found anything (in my logcat I don't have error). Could you help me to find out my problem.

My information about compilation, compiler and phone:

- Android Studio 1.0.1
- API 19 Android 4.4.4 (kitkat)
- Build 19
- Android phone version 4.4.4

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Function of my main activity:

```
Context context;
String sender;
String body;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get current context
    context = this;

    //App started
    Toast.makeText(context, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    CheckApp();
}

private void CheckApp() {

    sender = "1234";
    body = "Android sms body";

    //Get my package name
    final String myPackageName = getPackageName();

    //Check if my app is the default sms app
    if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(myPackageName)) {

        //Get default sms app
        String defaultSmsApp = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);

        //Change the default sms app to my app
        Intent intent = new Intent( Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
        intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);

        //Write the sms
        WriteSms(body, sender);

        //Change my sms app to the last default sms app
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
        intent2.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, defaultSmsApp);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
    else{

        //Write the sms
        WriteSms(body, sender);
    }
}

//Write the sms
private void WriteSms(String message, String phoneNumber) {

    //Put content values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, phoneNumber);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, message);

    //Insert the message
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
    else {
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
    }
}
```

Well, this is what i wanna do but with my own app and not with the app [Fake Text Message](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neurondigital.FakeTextMessage&hl=en) that downloaded to the play store.

Make the fake message and what should i see on my default sms app:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your app cannot be set as the default SMS app unless, at minimum, its manifest contains everything shown in the example here: [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1). Additionally, when the `ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT` Intent is fired, a confirmation dialog pops up, so I don't think your method is going to work like you're expecting.

Comment: As a side note, if you're just playing around on your own device running 4.4.4, you might check [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27709655/2850651) for a possible workaround.

Comment: I read the example shown in the post "Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat". All the extra stuff that I don't add to my manifest, seems to be use to manage sms, mms (recived, sent) with the network (not what i wanna do in my app). In my app i just wanna insert an sms such as the app [Fake Text Message](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.neurondigital.FakeTextMessage&hl=fr). By the way i wanna use my app for more than my phone.

Comment: Even if, i thought it was not what i have to do, i did it and it show me the confirmation dialog pops up, but it still doesn't send my fake message in default sms app.

Comment: If your code is the same as you've posted, then that's expected. Starting an Activity - in your case, the confirmation dialog - happens asynchronously, so the code execution does not pause after you call `startActivity(intent)`, and the `WriteSms()` method is called immediately, at which point you've not yet set your app as default.

Comment: I'm going to do that, thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike M. for your answers, I'm going to put the solution in the next post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the help from Mike M. I finally finished my program. So, this is the code that you must add to your app to be able to send sms without using network:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- My activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
    <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
    <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Main Activity:

```
Context context;
Button button;
String sender,body,defaultSmsApp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Get current context
    context = this;

    //Set composant
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    //Get default sms app
    defaultSmsApp = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);

    //Set the number and the body for the sms
    sender = "0042";
    body = "Android fake message";

    //Button to write to the default sms app
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Get the package name and check if my app is not the default sms app
            final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
            if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context).equals(myPackageName)) {

                //Change the default sms app to my app
                Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        }
    });
}

//Write to the default sms app
private void WriteSms(String message, String phoneNumber) {

    //Put content values
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, phoneNumber);
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, message);

    //Insert the message
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
    else {
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
    }

    //Change my sms app to the last default sms
    Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, defaultSmsApp);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

//Get result from default sms dialog pops up
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
            if (Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context).equals(myPackageName)) {

                //Write to the default sms app
                WriteSms(body, sender);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result of adding things in your manifest you must add 4 classes: SmsReceiver, MmsReceiver, ComposeSmsActivity and HeadlessSmsSendService. You can let them empty as shown below.

SmsReceiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

MmsReceiver:

```
public class MmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

ComposeSmsActivity:

```
public class ComposeSmsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

}
```

HeadlessSmsSendService:

```
public class HeadlessSmsSendService extends IntentService {
    public HeadlessSmsSendService() {
        super(HeadlessSmsSendService.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

If you need more help to understand this program have a look there:

[Youtube - DevBytes: Android 4.4 SMS APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdq0R2WQssQ)

[Android developers - Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

[Possiblemobile - KitKat SMS and MMS supports](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/11/kitkat-sms-mms-supports/)

Comment: Just beginning with Android developement - I found this to work (SMS is found in inbox after we click on the button).
But it works with no notifications about new SMS - and every time we click the button we must "confirm" that we will be using this app as defaul SMS app.
So - maybe not suitable for usecases when we would like to "experience the normal SMS lifecycle" (with notifications and without constant dialog confirmations etc.).

Comment: @Albentrix Cant we set the values of [Read](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#READ) and [Seen](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#SEEN) because as per the documentation it says seen is what used to set a notification for new message.