# Sending text via Wi-Fi when Wi-Fi is ON and received text as Normal message application

Tags: android, server, sms, wifi

I am making a Sms application in which i want to send text messages over Wi-Fi.
In other words if internet connection is ON then the message will be send over 
Wi-Fi and if there is no internet then the message will be send via app and carrier charges will be applied. I just want to know that is it possible in android? I heard that this can be done in Iphone through iMessage but is it possible to do that in android?
I am thinking that If Internet is ON then the message should be send to server and there is some algorithm on Server side that receive the message and send it to the person with the sender contact number and message.
Help me in this way what to do and how to do, any directions will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your thoughts are correct, however your question is very broad. Start developing the implementation you describe here and narrow down the question when you run into a specific problem

Comment: @TimCastelijns i just wanna know that is it possible or if there is already an app with such a thing exists in android?

Comment: Of course it is possible. And from the 500 million apps in the play store, Im sure there is at least 1 that does this

Comment: Ok thankyou Tim :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's only possible for carriers. The great deal is when the wi-fi is on, you need to send a message to the server, then the server uses a service for sending SMS to recipient. When there is no wi-fi, you just need to use android's SmsManager to send the message to recipient.

Another solution I found is based on this question [Android - Try to send fake sms to myself without mobile network usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572168/android-try-to-send-fake-sms-to-myself-without-mobile-network-usage)

You can use a service to send a push notification to recipient, and when you receive the push, you simulate a sms pushing the info into sms log, and notifying the user.

Comment: so basically there should be some service at server side that will send the sms to the receiver, this approach is fine right?