# Can we use default SMS Notification for Incoming custom generated Message?

Tags: android, smsmanager

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572168/android-try-to-send-fake-sms-to-myself-without-mobile-network-usage) we can send and receive fake sms in our Inbox without mobile network. My question is when we receive sms from our app can we call default Receive notification that mobile uses? I am using custom Notification and it's creating lots of bugs :( , I don't  want to use custom notification if it can do by SMSManger.

Comment: No, you can't do that. `SmsManager` really doesn't have anything to do with that Notification. The default SMS app creates that. The post you linked is showing how to set your app as the default in order to get write access to the Provider, and directly save a message there. `SmsManager` is not used for any of that. Furthermore, if your app is the default, it's responsible for creating that Notification anyway, and you can't force another app to show its own in place of it.

Comment: @MikeM. Glad that you are here! You've answered the same post that I linked. You're the best and I appreciate your answer. I will be glad that you will help me further while problem arises creating a messaging app. Thank you. Sorry for poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you cant. See, fake SMS are like writing SMS to message database of android. This is technically a message but not a message that received through network. If you are using AVD you will be familiar with this. There is an option in AVD that helps you to write messages and pretend it to be inbox messages, since AVD doesn't have network. 
And, coming to default notifications, I think there are no such things provided by android.What ever the notification is you have to create it. And, bugs are to be solved, no offence!. You question will be more interesting if you had included a few bugs you encountered.

Comment: Thanks @Anuroop Pendela I am currently trying to find  bug myself. If I can't find it by today, I will post my problems  and codes here.  Anyway thanks for your answer.